# Class MailerPHP strange behaviour (looping array of address)

Tags: php, email

I am using Class MailerPHP to send emails on the website. Actually is working perfect as it have to work but there is some strange stuff that i can not figure out why is like this.

**1. I have an array of address that i am sending emails, the array is like this:**

```
    $email = new sendEmail();
    $_ADMIN_EMAIL = array('first_email', 'second_email', 'third_email');
    $email->setEmail($_ADMIN_EMAIL);
```

The problem is when is sending emails, is sending 3 emails:
1. sending to first_email
2. after sending to first_email and second_email
3. and at the end sending to first_email, second_email and third_email

I would like to send only one to all 3 and do not send 3 times email, i do not understand why is sending like this.

**2. And second problem is i am using my Google account to connect to the SMTP to send emails, and i do not know why in the TO field of the email is showing my gmail address that i connect to the SMTP, i setup which address to show there and is showing + my gmail account:**

I have this configuration only and i didn't put anywhere else my gmail account only for SMTP connection:

```
    public $Username      = 'my_gmail_account_to connect_to_smtp';
    public $Password      = 'my_gmail_account_password';
```

The result of this when i get emails is first email that i setup to show for reply + my_gmail_account_to connect_to_smtp, i need to take out my_gmail_account_to connect_to_smtp from the email that the user will not see it.

If you need for information about the code i use please let me know i will put.

**All the code that i send email:**

```
$_ADMIN_EMAIL = array("first_email", "second_email", "third_email");

$email2 = new sendEmail();

$email2->setSubject("Subject");
$email2->setUserName($_USER['name']);
$email2->setMT4Account($_USER['login']);
$email2->setDate($_USER['date']);
$email2->setAmount($_USER['amount']);
$email2->setCurrency($_USER['currency']);
$email2->setRegisteredBankAccount($_USER['type']);
$email2->setBankAccountName($_USER['card']);

$email2->setTemplate('template_for_the_email');
$email2->setEmail($_ADMIN_EMAIL);
echo $email2->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$_ADMIN_EMAIL = array('first_email', 'second_email', 'third_email');

foreach($_ADMIN_EMAIL as $ademail)
 {
  $email->setEmail($ademail);
 }
```

Comment: in this way i just tried, but is not sending at all emails @sanki

Comment: @ionluchian: Well it should, I'm not sure what's wrong. Can you please post the whole PHPMailer related code here.

Comment: i put all the code for the email, please see my updated question @sanki

Comment: actually am using PHPMailer just i created some custom scripts that allow me in a very easy way to use it... @sanki

Comment: @ionluchian: That's pretty cool. Unfortunately since this is a customized form of PHPMailer which I'm not aware of, is making it's even more difficult for me to sort out the issue.